# Monkey patch unpermitted_parameters in actioncontroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I was going through one of the [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34617/files) in rails 6  where they have added a color property to the unpermitted parameter. I found it quite imperative for my application because we usually have a very long log. I thought to include the same functionality in my Rails 5 application

I created an ext folder inside my app and there added the below code

And in initializers folder

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/ext/action_controller_override.rb"
```

file_name: **action_controller_override.rb**

```
ActionController::LogSubscriber.class_eval do

  def unpermitted_parameters(event)
      debug do
        unpermitted_keys = event.payload[:keys]
        color("Unpermitted parameter#{'s' if unpermitted_keys.size > 1}: #{unpermitted_keys.map { |e| ":#{e}" }.join(", ")}", RED)
      end
    end

end
```

But the above code giving me error.

Could not log **unpermitted_parameters.action_controller event. NameError: uninitialized constant RED**

So, can anyone shed a light on it and tell me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution

```
"Unpermitted parameter#{'s' if unpermitted_keys.size > 1}: #{unpermitted_keys.map { |e| ":#{e}" }.join(", ")}".green
```

The keyword green is given by colorize gem

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to keep your code under `config/initializers` folder as `.rb` file which will open class and override as per your code.

Also, Have a look on [3 ways to monkey patch](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/)

Comment: I am getting an error Could not log "unpermitted_parameters.action_controller" event. NameError: uninitialized constant RED

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Yes I guess you have to define constant RED as defined in that existing file.